# Not able to set Landscape orientation in mPdf - niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I am trying to generate the pdf using `mPdf - niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf` in laravel 5.5. But every time I am getting the pdf in portrait mode.

```
public function showCertificate()
{
    $data = [ 'name' => 'John Doe', 'prize' => '1st Prize'];
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('certificates.show', 
        $data, 
        [], 
        [ 
          'title' => 'Certificate', 
          'orientation' => 'L'
        ]);
    return $pdf->stream('certificate.pdf');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was finally able to get it resolved by using `format` to `A4-L` along with `orientation`. My working code is given below.

```
public function showCertificate()
{
    $data = [ 'name' => 'John Doe', 'prize' => '1st Prize'];
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('certificates.show', 
        $data, 
        [], 
        [ 
          'title' => 'Certificate', 
          'format' => 'A4-L',
          'orientation' => 'L'
        ]);
    return $pdf->stream('certificate.pdf');
}
```

I saw this [issue](https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf/issues/40) and inferred from there to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another subtle thing you may be missing if you encounter this same problem...take my case for example, I did not add the empty array syntax `[]` before the options/config array...

**This will NOT work**

```php
public function showCertificate()
{
    $data = [ 'name' => 'John Doe', 'prize' => '1st Prize'];
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('certificates.show', 
        $data, 
      //  [], I removed the emptyy arrayy
        [ 
          'title' => 'Certificate', 
          'format' => 'A4-L',
          'orientation' => 'L'
        ]);
    return $pdf->stream('certificate.pdf');
}
```

**This will work**

```php
public function showCertificate()
{
    $data = [ 'name' => 'John Doe', 'prize' => '1st Prize'];
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('certificates.show', 
        $data, 
       [],
        [ 
          'title' => 'Certificate', 
          'format' => 'A4-L',
          'orientation' => 'L'
        ]);
    return $pdf->stream('certificate.pdf');
}
```

Take not of `[]`.